# Java streams with generics

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a generic function which accepts `Collection<? extends T> ts`.

I'm also passing:

`Function<? extends T, ? extends K> classifier` which maps each item `T` to a key `K` (possible to have duplicates)

`Function<? extends T, Integer> evaluator` which gives an integer value for the item.

The function itself has a *built-in* calculation ("`int to int`") for every produced `Integer` (could be something like squaring for our example)

Finally, I'd like to sum all of the values for each key.

So the end result is: `Map<K, Integer>`.

**For example,**
Let's say we have the list `["a","a", "bb"]` and we use `Function.identity` to classify,  `String::length` to evaluate and squaring as the built-in function. Then the returned map will be: `{"a": 2, "b": 4}`

How can I do that? (I guess that preferably using `Collectors.groupingBy`)

Comment: Because we're also squaring

Comment: What did your search and research bring up? Have you tried something?

Comment: @OleV.V., yeah actually tried to integrate it with the `Collectors.groupingBy`. It didn't work out

Comment: @yaseco Show, don't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public static <T,K> Map<K,Integer> mapper (
    Collection<T> ts,
    Function<T, K> classifier,
    Function<T, Integer> evaluator,
    Function<Integer,Integer> calculator) 
{
     return
        ts.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,
                                         Collectors.summingInt(t->evaluator.andThen(calculator).apply(t))));
}
```

The output for:

```
System.out.println (mapper(Arrays.asList("a","a","bb"),Function.identity(),String::length,i->i*i));
```

is

```
{bb=4, a=2}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Eran! (Apparently, I was quite close to the answer but you closed the gap for me - Cheers!)

Comment: I do need to understand the `downstream` part better

Comment: @yaseco Collectors.summingInt() allows you to map each of the T elements of a given group to an int and then sum all these ints. `t->evaluator.andThen(calculator).apply(t)` takes a T instance, applies the `evaluator` function on it and then applies the `calculator` function of the result.

Comment: `t->evaluator.andThen(calculator).apply(t)` will repeatedly invoke `andThen`, constructing a new `Function` instance for every evaluation of this lambda expression. The straight-forward way to apply a method to the result of another would be a nested invocation like `t -> calculator.apply(evaluator.apply(t))`. Or, if it really has to be a new functional construct, `evaluator.andThen(calculator)::apply` will invoke `andThen` only once and capture the result.

Answer (score 2):

Or another approach:

```
private static <K, T> Map<K, Integer> map(Collection<? extends T> ts,
                                          Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,
                                          Function<? super T, Integer> evaluator,
                                          Function<Integer, Integer> andThen) {

    return ts.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 classifier,
                 Collectors.mapping(evaluator.andThen(andThen),
                                    Collectors.reducing(0, Integer::sum))
             ));

}
```

And use it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(map(
        Arrays.asList("a", "a", "bb"),
        Function.identity(),
        String::length,
        x -> x * x));

}
```

Comment: It’s funny, how far people go, just to use method references. Here, using `evaluator::apply` and `andThen::apply` to convert a `Function` to a `Function`. Since these are already `Function` instances, a simple `Collectors.mapping(evaluator, Collectors.mapping(andThen, …))` would do and once you realize that neither, lambda expression nor method reference is required, you can use a single combined `Collectors.mapping(evaluator.andThen(andThen), …)`, unlike the other answer, this will not repeatedly invoke `andThen`…